# Как отравлять сообщение в мой лс, на какой сервер зашол мой бот discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Пробовал данную версию кода.

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
     await bot.fetch_user(user_id='My id').send('Hello')
```

Но выдаёт ошибку.

```
TypeError: fetch_user() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'user_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С версии библиотеки 2.0 `user_id` больше нельзя использовать как keyword-аргумент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто указывайте `id` без названия аргумента. И еще, `send` — тоже асинхронный метод. Поэтому как-то так должно быть:

```py
await (await bot.fetch_user(372468723564675427)).send('Hello')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое